# Dynamic navigation mesh changes

Tags: path-finding, navmesh

I'm currently trying to convert from grids to navigation meshes for pathfinding, since grids are either too coarse for accurate navigation, or too fine to be useful for object tracking.

While my map is fairly static, and the navigation mesh could be created in advance, this is somewhat of a tower defense game, where objects can be placed to block paths, so I need a way to recalculate portions of the navigation mesh to allow pathing around them.

Is there any existing documentation on good ways to do this? I'm still very new to navigation meshes, so the prospect of modifying them to cut or fill holes sounds daunting.

**EDIT:**
To be clear, I'm looking for solutions that use a polygon navigation mesh, not a grid. I currently use grids, but I'm trying to move away from using them. It is the efficient dynamic modification of that polygon mesh that I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: If you already have a grid generator, you can easily build an octree to optimize away useless grid cells, and generate your navmesh from that octree.

Comment: I hadn't considered an octree/quadtree, thanks for that. However ultimately I'd like to get away from square grids entirely, as their axis alignment doesn't match the path angles I'm hoping to allow in my maps. Using grids currently means making a rough approximation of any angles. I'd prefer my navmesh not be limited by that approximation.

Comment: You're not necessarily limited to generating the mesh naively from the quadtree, it's just a starting point, you can build a more accurate post process that circumvents the rectangular nature of a quadtree using line of sight tests for example.

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you are doing now and what is the problem with what you are doing? Is the issue (of the question) splitting nav mesh cells into multiple cells? Modifying them when blocking objects are added to the map?

Comment: Yes. Right now I use a grid, which works, but is too coarse to accurately map out angled paths. If I reduce the grid size to make it fit better, I end up slowing down pathfinding, since it has too many grid points to search. I'd like to switch to navmeshes to fix both problems.

Comment: But where it was easy to add collisions to a grid, it looks much more complex for navmeshes. Obstacles could split a single cell into multiple cells, it could exist on the border between cells and require splitting multiple cells. And the opposite, removing an obstacle and reassembling the neighboring cells into larger pieces to fill the hole. These are things I'd like to learn to do, and I assume are possible, but I haven't been able to find how so far.

Comment: http://www.david-gouveia.com/portfolio/pathfinding-on-a-2d-polygonal-map/

Comment: since my answer was not relevant, I've deleted it, to not receive the bounty

Comment: You still need the grid in order to optimize collision checks, you'll be doing wrong by removing it.

Comment: In my game there is no collision between units, only against the map and stationary buildings. So long as the navmesh is updated when a building is placed or removed, pathfinding should take care of avoiding collisions. That said, I'll still be using a grid for proximity detection, but at a much coarser level than needed for pathfinding.

Comment: So far, the best option I've seen is to precalculate polygon routes (from the link Jon posted), and use something like the Clipper library (http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) for polygon recalculation when adding/removing obstacles.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), which is also used for internet routing.

In short, you must create a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) where each edge is a path from one node to another. These could be pre-calculated if some of your geometry is fixed.

For each starting point, you will order the nodes according to their distance from the destination. Then apply Dijkstra's algorithm through the graph to build routing tables for each one. The first route in the table will be the shortest path. Each route after that will be a variation depending on which nodes are blocked. These extra routes could be calculated as necessary, provided their order is maintained in the table (they should be ordered by the sum of their edge lengths). You'll refer to these routes again when a node is changed (blocked/unblocked).

You can then add and remove nodes by splitting edges and moving the new midpoint, then recalculating from the origin node.